# Android custom lint rule reports an error but still build success

Tags: android-studio, static-analysis, lint

I have a simple custom lint rule that changes the severity of HardCodedText from warning to error

```
<lint>
    <!-- list of issues to configure -->
    <issue id="HardcodedText" severity="error"/>
</lint>
```

And in the layout file

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Hardcode String"/> //this line has the red underline reports an error as expected
```

My lint options

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError true // stop build when lint reports errors
    lintConfig file("lint.xml")
}
```

The Android Studio reports HardcodedText as an error. However when I click the run button, the project still build successfully. What am I missing, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following code in dependency block in your module build.gradle

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'compileDebugSources' ||
            task.name == 'compileReleaseSources') {
        task.dependsOn lint
        task.mustRunAfter lint
    }
}
```